# How can I merge Tensorflow Dataset columns?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-datasets

I have a Keras model that takes an input layer with shape (n, 288, 1), of which 288 is the number of features. I am using a TensorFlow dataset `tf.data.experimental.make_batched_features_dataset` and my input layer will be (n, 1, 1) which means it gives one feature to the model at a time. How can I make an input tensor with the shape of (n, 288, 1)? I mean how can I use all my features in one tensor?

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `kubeflow` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the shape of your input in the Keras input layer. Here an example code demonstrating with dummy data demonstrating the same.

```py
import tensorflow as tf

## Creating dummy data for demo
def make_sample():
    return tf.random.normal([288, 1])

n_samples = 100
samples = [make_sample() for _ in range(n_samples)]
labels = [tf.random.uniform([1]) for _ in range(n_samples)]


# Use tf.data to create dataset
batch_size = 4

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((samples, labels))
dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)

# Build keras function model
inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=[288, 1], name='input')
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)(inputs)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[inputs], outputs=[x])

# Compile loss and optimizer
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='sgd', metrics=['mae'])
model.fit(dataset, epochs=1)
```